# Why does input tag break code in Firefox version 18.0.1?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firefox

Our kiosks at my work use a very old version of Firefox, specifically version 18.0.1, and I've noticed that if I have a form that includes an input tag, that the page will break and go blank.  My goal is to create a dynamic form depending upon specific circumstances.  I've checked the console in Firefox and it doesn't list what the error was that triggered it other than that it was from the input tag.  This is the error I receive:

```
[12:09:39.928] The above error occurred in the <input> component:
    in input (created by ServiceReport)
    in div (created by ServiceReport)
    in div (created by ServiceReport)
    in ServiceReport (created by Route)
    in Route
    in Switch
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
```

Here is the portion of my code where the input tag is being used:

```
RenderPhoneInput(){

        let kiosks = this.state.KiosksDB;

        console.log(this.state.KiosksServerID);
        let kiosk = this.state.KiosksServerID;

        let divToReturn = null;

        if(kiosk != null){
            for(let i = 0; i < kiosks.length; i++){
                if(kiosk[0].KioskID == kiosks[i].KioskID && kiosks[i].ValidPhone == "No"){
                    divToReturn = (
                        <div>
                            <h3>Phone Number (required)</h3>
                            <input id="PhoneInput" type="text"></input>

                            <h3>Carrier</h3>
                            <input id="CarrierInput" type="text"></input>
                        </div>
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        return divToReturn;

    }

render(){
 return(
  ... form

{this.RenderPhoneInput()}

                    <h3>Did you update the page counts?</h3>
                    <select id="UpdatePageCountSelect" tabIndex="19" >
                        <option  key="0" value=""></option>
                        <option  key="1" value="Yes" checked>Yes, I updated the page counts</option>
                        <option  key="2" value="No" checked>No, I did not update the page counts</option>
                        <option  key="3" value="UnKnown" checked>No, I dont't know how to update the page counts</option>
                    </select>

                    <h3>Documents Left</h3>
                    <p id="DocsInput"> </p>

... Rest of form
 );

}
```

Tags I know that work in this form so far are, select, textarea, buttons, and other basic html tags.  I'm just confused why all these other tags work properly, but the input tag doesn't.  I checked and made sure that Firefox had support for this and it shows that it does.  If anyone knows why this might be breaking my code, or has any suggestions as to what I can do to fix it, I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're using some kind of template framework, add the appropriate tag to the question.

Comment: @Barmar I'm using the reactjs framework.